# Access C++ static member from another class

Tags: c++, static, member

I've a class like the following:

```
class Parameter {
public:
    Parameter();
    virtual ~Parameter();

    bool parse();

    static int WindowWidth;
    static int WindowHeight;
    ....
};
```

Now, in my main I go with:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Parameter parameter;
    Controller controller;

    parameter.parse("parameter.ini");
    controller.initialise();

    return 0;
}
```

Now, in the Controller object I'd need to access the static members of the Parameter class. Therefore, I'm just doing:

```
Controller::Controller() {
    m_numberOfSweepers = Parameter::NumberOfSweepers;
    m_ticks = Parameter::NumberOfTicks;
    m_window_cx = Parameter::WindowWidth;
    m_window_cy = Parameter::WindowHeight;
}
```

Everything compiles fine. Taking out GDB, I can see that within the parser method of theparameter object, the correct values are inside the static members. But within the Controller::Controller() method, I just get garbage.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**
In the cpp file of the Parameter class, I do the following (outside of any method):

```
int Parameter::WindowWidth;
int Parameter::WindowHeight;
```

Comment: Did you initialize the static members? With what values?

Comment: How do you make sure `Parameter::WindowWidth` is initialized before Controller?

Comment: @David: I didn't initialise them with a value. I made an EDIT on the post.

Comment: Why don't you initialize them to 0? Maybe that will help.

Comment: static member default initialize to 0, but you could manually set to 0.

Comment: @Tectu all static members of `Parameter` are garbage in Controller?

Comment: @billz yep, all of them.

Comment: @Tectu Where are you calling the `Controller` constructor? Only in main where you create the objects?

Comment: @David only in the main.
I did now move the part where it copies the Parameter members into the initialising method of the Controller class since I just need them there and now everything works great. Therefore billz was somehow right ^^
Thanks for your help, guys!

Comment: http://ideone.com/EQNkN1, default initialized correctly.

Comment: @billz Comment above your last

Comment: yup. cool if the issue is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is just order of initialization. Here, you construct the controller:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  Parameter parameter;
  Controller controller;
```

When this happens, the constructor for controller is called, doing the following:

```
Controller::Controller() {
  m_numberOfSweepers = Parameter::NumberOfSweepers; // uninitialized garbage
  m_ticks = Parameter::NumberOfTicks; // uninitialized garbage
  m_window_cx = Parameter::WindowWidth; // uninitialized garbage
  m_window_cy = Parameter::WindowHeight; // uninitialized garbage
}
```

Then you initialize parameter by parsing the ini file. But controller got these values **before** you did that. **Unless Controller is storing references to the static members, it is just going to keep those garbage values.**

A simple fix would be moving the code from your constructor into your Controller's 'initialise' method. For example,

```
Controller::Controller() : m_numberOfSweepers(0)
                         , m_ticks(0)
                         , m_window_cx(0)
                         , m_window_cy(0)
{
  // now empty
}

void Controller::initialise()
{
  m_numberOfSweepers = Parameter::NumberOfSweepers;
  m_ticks = Parameter::NumberOfTicks;
  m_window_cx = Parameter::WindowWidth;
  m_window_cy = Paramter::WindowHeight;
}
```

That would fix the current problem, assuming you call it in the proper order. But I think this design is maybe a little messy. Why do you need a seperate class for these parameters?

If you want to stick with it, maybe try to give it a less general name, like ControllerParameters or something? Anyways, good luck. Have a nice day!

**EDIT**
It might also serve you well to initialize those statics, just so they aren't total garbage. Garbage is bad. Just say something like:

```
int Parameter::WindowWidth = 0;
int Parameter::WindowHeight = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Your order of initialization is wrong. One possible way is, in main do:

```
Parameter parameter;
parameter.parse("parameter.ini");

Controller controller;
controller.initialise();
```